# JavaScript FetchAPI giving undifined results, thinking I need to move the fetch_call function but not sure where

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Trying to connect to the Unsplash API but I'm having trouble figuring out why it isn't working. I've tried moving the fetch inside the my show_data function as well as creating its own fetch_call function and neither seem to work. Any ideas?

```js
const IMAGE_URI = "API_KEY";

function show_data(json) {
  const image_data = json.results;
  const gallary = document.querySelector("#gallery div");
  let copy = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < image_data.length; i++) {
    copy += '<div class="image-container">';
    copy +=
      '<img src="' +
      image_data[i].urls.regular +
      '" alt="wallpaper" class="wallpaper"';
    copy += '<div class="overlay-content">';
    copy += '<div><img src="assets/user.svg" alt="user">';
    copy += '<p>"' + image_data[i].users.name + '"</p></div>"';
    copy += '<div><img src="assets/like-before.svg" alt="likes">';
    copy +=
      '<p>"' + image_data[i].users.total_likes + '"</p></div></div></div>"';
  }
  if (image_data == null || image_data == undefined) {
    copy += "<p>Can not Connect to Unsplash</p>";
  }
  image_data.innerHTML = copy;
}

function fetch_call() {
  fetch(IMAGE_URI)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      show_data(json);
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", show_data, false);
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting undefined results, *what* is not working? Your `fetch` invocation looks fine.

Comment: Maybe just `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fetch_call, false);` ?

Comment: `image_data` is not an HTML element at `image_data.innerHTML = copy;`

Comment: image_data is coming up as undefined.

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(json))` log within `.then()`? Does `json` have a `"results"` property?

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fetch_call, false);` Still comes up with image_data[i] being undefined.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(json))` logs all the needed information from the API.

Comment: Then there should be no issue if `json.results` exists, except for the fact that `image_data` is not a `DOM` element at `image_data.innerHTML = copy;`

Comment: Add `console.log(json)` output to the question

Comment: `console.log(json)` logs all the requested information from the API.

Comment: Change `const image_data = json.results;` to `const image_data = json;`

Answer (score 1):

The posted code does not call `fetch_call`. Try changing

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", show_data, false);
```

to

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fetch_call, false);
```

Then `fetch_call` can call `show_data` with actual JSON results.

Answer (score 0):

Because `image_data` is not a DOM element at `image_data.innerHTML = copy;` all I to do was change `image_data.innerHTML = copy;` to `gallery.innerHTML = copy;`. Guess I just overlooked it.